# How can I structure a Backbone.View based plugin so that its nested views can be extended individually?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dependency-injection, backbone.js, requirejs

I am designing a generic object browser plugin which functions similar to OS X's Finder in column view. I have divided up the interface in to several nested views, the browser, the columns and the objects.

I will be using this plugin in several scenarios where the browser view, object view and column view may or may not need to be customised. Sometimes the objects will be files and folders for example.

[This is OS X's Finder in column view in case you don't know what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHu19.png)

At the moment I am using RequireJS to pass around the dependencies however in order to simply inherit and extend the ObjectView, I must replace the entire stack.

Is there any better structure where the plugin can be extended but only part of?

BrowserView.js

```
var BrowserView = Backbone.View.extend({

    open: function () {
        var collectionView = new CollectionView( {collection: objects} );
    }

});
```

CollectionView.js

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function () {

        this.collection.each( function (object) {
            var objectView = new ObjectView( {model: objects} );

            objectView.bind('click', this.select, this);

            this.container.append( objectView.el );

            objectView.render();

            this.objectViews.push(objectView);
        }, this );

    },

});
```

ObjectView.js

```
var ObjectView = Backbone.View.extend({

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put these views in the same module.

The purpose of a module - whether you're using RequireJS or just plain old JavaScript modules - is to encapsulate a set of related objects and functions, for a specific purpose. In this case, your purpose is the Finder View.

By keeping all of the related objects in the same file, you'll have more freedom and flexibility for how you make the objects work together.

---

As a side note, but related to what you're doing, you might be able to get some ideas for how to make this work from the "CompositeView" of my Backbone.Marionette plugin. I've built a hierarchical tree-view of folders and files with it before, and the column view of Finder would be fairly easy to build with it, too.

Note that I'm not suggesting you need to use my plugin. Rather, I think it might be helpful in figuring out how you want to structure your code.

I've got a blog post that talks about it here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

You can find the code and docs here: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette

And the annotated source code for the composite view is here: http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-26